# Rest api development

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a use case where there are around 500 strings as input for fetching the details of these 500 inputs.

Based on which I will be returning a result of 500 complex elements as output.

Now the HTTP GET limitation comes in between of using GET here. Is resorting to POST a solution?

Comment: consider batches  no?

Comment: This is from a web service producer perspective, and the consumer has a limitation that they will be sending this request for 500 strings

Comment: Sounds like this shouldn't be a REST webservice at all.

Comment: This needs to be developed as REST service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service provider perspective says 'we accept http POST" and consumer perspective says OK

Comment: Thank you @Drew but does that mean it cannot be done?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a POST method and put the strings in the request body (entity).  Don't use the query parameters (they are limited in size).  HTTP doesn't have a limitation on request/response body size.  Use the POST method, because GET doesn't support a request body.